# Android dialog closes on any physical keypress

Tags: android, android-dialog, keyevent

I have this dialog, with just a textView and no buttons. It displays some info and I need to change info on key press left and right. Unfortunately the dialog closes on any key.
This code in MainActivity invokes the dialog (redundant code omitted)

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            InfoDialog infoDialog = new InfoDialog();
            infoDialog.showDialog(this,currentDateAndTime,chn);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

and this is the dialog code

```
public class InfoDialog {
    private int counter = 0;
    private Dialog dialog;
    
    public void showDialog(final Activity activity, final String DateTime, final ChannelList.Channel chn){
        dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.info_dialog);

        counter = 0;
        setDialogText(chn,DateTime,counter);

        dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
                    if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        if (counter>0) counter--;
                        setDialogText(chn,DateTime,counter);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
                    if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        if (counter<chn.infoText.size()-1) counter++;
                        setDialogText(chn,DateTime,counter);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
                return false;
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

when I press any button, the dialog closes, even if the onKey has been invoked.
Did I miss something? how do I handle keypresses for my dialog only? (other dialogs may use same keys for different operation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, inside `InfoDialog` you are setting `DialogInterface.OnKeyListener` and on the bottom of `onKey` method you are calling `dialog.dismiss()`, try to remove this line... (and also `return true` for any case)

Comment: Thanks, I thought the Return in the If would have skipped the Dismiss and made it quit the method onKey

Comment: it would, but you have `return` lines only if key is `KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT` or `KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT` + action is `ACTION_UP`, any other key+action pair would call `dismiss` (so even `KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT` + `ACTION_DOWN` - pressing key)